# Passing command line argument to Presto Query

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, presto

I m a newbie to python. I want to pass a command-line argument to my presto query which is inside a function and then writes the result as a CSV file. But when I try to run it on the terminal it says '`Traceback (most recent call last): File "function2.py", line 3, in <module> from pyhive import presto ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyhive'`

The pyhive requirement is already satisfied. Please find attached my code:

```
from sys import argv
import argparse
from pyhive import presto
import prestodb
import csv
import sys


import pandas as pd

connection = presto.connect(host='xyz',port=8889,username='test')
cur = connection.cursor()
print('Connection Established')


def func1(object,start,end):
    object = argv[1]
    start = argv[2]
    end = argv[3]
    result = cur.execute("""
    with map_date as 
    (
     SELECT 
     object, 
     epoch,
     timestamp,
     date,
     map_agg(name, value) as map_values
    from hive.schema.test1
    where object = '${object}' 
    and (epoch >= '${start}' and epoch <= '${end}')
    and name in ('x','y')
    GROUP BY object,epoch,timestamp,date
    order by timestamp asc
    )
    SELECT
      epoch
    , timestamp
    , CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'x') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['x'] ELSE NULL END AS x
    , CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'y') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['y'] ELSE NULL END AS y
    , object
    , date AS date
    from map_date
    """)
rows = cur.fetchall()
print('Query Finished')     #Returns the list with one entry for each record
fp = open('/Users/xyz/Desktop/Python/function.csv', 'w')
print('File Created')
myFile = csv.writer(fp)
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]     #store the headers in variable called 'colnames'
myFile.writerow(colnames)    #write the header to the file
myFile.writerows(rows)
fp.close()

func1(object,start,end)

cur.close()
connection.close()
```

How can I pass the command line argument to my Presto query which is written inside a function?
Any help is much appreciated. Thank you In advance!

Comment: your current problem is `pyhive` and you have to resove it before you can use `presto`. if in code doesn't work `impor pyhive` then you don't have it. Maybe you have two pythons installed and you installed `pyhive` in other python. You can use `python -m pip install pyhive`  to install it with python which you use to run code - `python script.py`

Comment: @furas Thanks for replying, I will install python but how will I add the command line argument in my code? Can you help me with that, please? Thanks!

Comment: you should have command line arguments in `sys.argv` and you can use it directly in any place - inside and outside functons. Or you can send it as functions arguments `func1(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])`

Comment: @furas Can you give an example of how I can achieve this in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only describe how to pass command line arguments to function and query.

---

If you define function

```
def func1(object, start, end):
    # code
```

then you have to send values as varaibles and you have to use `sys.argv` outside function

```
connection = presto.connect(host='xyz', port=8889, username='test')  # PEP8: spaces after commas
cur = connection.cursor()
print('Connection Established')

object_ = sys.argv[1]   # PEP8: there is class `object` so I add `_` to create different name
start = sys.argv[2]
end = sys.argv[3]

func1(object_, start, end)

cur.close()
connection.close()
```

You don't have to use the same names outside function

```
args1 = sys.argv[1]
args2 = sys.argv[2]
args3 = sys.argv[3]

func1(args1, args2, args3)
```

and you can even do

```
func1(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

becuse when you run this line then python gets definition `def func1(object, start, end):` and it creates local variables with names `object, start, end` inside `func1` and it assigns external value to these local variables

```
object=objec_, start=start, end=end
```

or

```
object=args1, start=args2, end=args2
```

or

```
object=sys.argv[1], start=sys.argv[1], end=sys.argv[1]
```

---

It would be good to send explicitly also `cur` to function

```
def func1(cur, object_, start, end):
    # code
```

and

```
func1(cur, sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

---

I don't know what you try to do in SQL query but Python uses `{start}` (without `$`) to put value in string (Bash uses `${start}`) and it needs prefix `f` to create `f-string` - `f"""... {start}...."""`. Without `f` you have to use normal string formatting `"""... {start}....""".format(start=start)`

---

```
import sys
import csv
from pyhive import presto

# --- functions ----

def func1(cur, object_, start, end):  # PEP8: spaces after commas
    
    # Python use `{star} {end}`, Bash uses `${start} ${end}`
    
    # String needs prefix `f` to use `{name} {end}` in f-string
    # or you have to use `"{start} {end}".format(start=value1, end=value2)`
    
    result = cur.execute(f"""
    WITH map_date AS 
    (
      SELECT 
        object, 
        epoch,
        timestamp,
        date,
        map_agg(name, value) AS map_values
      FROM hive.schema.test1
      WHERE object = '{object_}' 
        AND (epoch >= '{start}' AND epoch <= '{end}')
        AND name IN ('x','y')
      GROUP BY object,epoch,timestamp,date
      ORDER BY timestamp asc
    )
    SELECT
      epoch,
      timestamp,
      CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'x') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['x'] ELSE NULL END AS x,
      CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'y') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['y'] ELSE NULL END AS y,
      object,
      date AS date
    FROM map_date
    """)

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]  # store the headers in variable called 'colnames'

    print('Query Finished')  # returns the list with one entry for each record

    fp = open('/Users/xyz/Desktop/Python/function.csv', 'w')
    
    my_file = csv.writer(fp)   # PEP8: lower_case_names for variables
    my_file.writerow(colnames)  # write the header to the file
    my_file.writerows(rows)
    
    fp.close()

    print('File Created')

# --- main ---

connection = presto.connect(host='xyz', port=8889, username='test')  # PEP8: spaces after commas
cur = connection.cursor()
print('Connection Established')

#object_ = sys.argv[1]   # PEP8: there is class `object` so I add `_` to create different name
#start = sys.argv[2]
#end = sys.argv[3]
#func1(cur, object_, start, end)

func1(cur, sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])

cur.close()
connection.close()
```

---

If you plan to use `argparse`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-o', '--object', help='object to search')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start',  help='epoch start')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--end',    help='epoch end')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

and then

```
func1(cur, args.object, args.start, args.end)
```

---

```
import argparse

# ... imports and functions ...

# --- main ---

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--object', help='object to search')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start',  help='epoch start')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--end',    help='epoch end')
#parser.add_argument('-D', '--debug', action='store_true', help='debug (display extra info)')
args = parser.parse_args()

#if args.debug:
#    print(args)

connection = presto.connect(host='xyz', port=8889, username='test')  # PEP8: spaces after commas
cur = connection.cursor()
print('Connection Established')

func1(cur, args.object, args.start, args.end)

cur.close()
```